# jQuery: how do I bind a function to some event that occurs immediately after the mouseup event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to invoke a function immediately after a text selection has been made. I currently have a function invoked on `mouseup`, but this is still before a selection is finished.

So, how do I invoke a function immediately after a selection is made?

EDIT: there is a .select() for text fields, but I'm looking for selections anywhere in the DOM, mainly spans and divs and such.

Comment: text, a text selection. one made with the mouse? =\

Answer (score 2):

have you tried the `select` event? if jQuery is a available in your app, you can do this:

```
$("#someElement").select(function(e) {
    // do something!
})
```

for regular text (i.e. not an input), the suggestion from @mrtsherman below should work:

```
$( document ).bind( "mouseup", function(e) {
    var text = getSelected();

    if ( text ) {
        // do something with the selected text
    }
});

function getSelected() {
    if ( window.getSelection ) {
        return window.getSelection();
    } else if ( document.getSelection ) {
        return document.getSelection();
    } else {
        var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
        if ( selection.text ) {
            return selection.text;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
};
```

hope that helps! cheers.

Comment: "The select event is sent to an element when the user makes a text selection inside it. This event is limited to <input type="text"> fields and <textarea> boxes." http://api.jquery.com/select/

Comment: great. haha. yeah I need this to work in divs and spans and such.

Comment: I like it. Does that event contain any information about what the selected text was? I grabbed a function from a google search for this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/BdV99/

Comment: you can use rangy for getting selection data. it's cross browser. and the most reliable way to do selection stuff.